# Send TraceId across Threads

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

We have a distributed application following microservice Architecture. In one of our microservice we are following producer-consumer pattern.

The producer receives requests, persists it to database, pushes the request into a BlockingQueue and sends the response back to the client. The consumer running on a separate thread is listening to the blocking queue. The moment it gets the request object it performs specific operations on it.

The request received by the producer is persisted to the database asynchronously using CompleteableFutures.

The problem here is how to forward TraceId to the methods processing the requestObject inside consumer thread. Since the consumer thread might process these objects much later after the response is sent to the consumer.

Also how to forward the traceId across Asynchronous calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question. I think that what you can do is to persist the request together with its headers. Then on the consumer side you can use the `SpanExtractor` interface in a similar way as we do here - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/blob/v1.3.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-sleuth-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/web/TraceFilter.java#L351 (`Span parent = spanExtractor().joinTrace(new HttpServletRequestTextMap(request));`). That means that from the `HttpServletRequest` we're extracting values to build a span. Then, once you've retrieved the `Span`, you can just use `Tracer#continueSpan(Span)` method before processing, and then `Tracer#detach(Span)` in the finally block. E.g.

```
Span parent = spanExtractor().joinTrace(new HttpServletRequestTextMap(request));
try {
   tracer.continueSpan(parent);
   // do whatever you need
} catch(Exception e) {
  tracer.addTag("error", doSthWithTheExceptionMsg(e));
} finally {
  tracer.detach(parent); 
}
```

Comment: We'll try doing this as well, but what we're doing right now is, persisting the traceId, then in the consumer thread we make a call to :-

`Span parent = Span.builder().traceId(Span.hexToId(traceId)).build();
  tracer.createSpan("ConsumerSpan", parent);`

Do you see any drawbacks with this approach?

Comment: moreover the consumer again spawns multiple threads as all the calls inside consumer are async, what would be the right approach to deal with this?

Comment: It looks ok in my opinion. Do you observe any problems?

Comment: None so far, Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Marcin, 

Going by this approach, everytime I am making a http request using restTemplate, a new TraceId is generated rather than forwarding the same TraceId also I am not getting x-b3-traceId as a response Header.

Comment: Is your RestTemplate a bean? Is it generated on the client side or the server side? If it's not a bean then it will be generated on the server side since the client side will not be instrumented.

Comment: yes it's a bean and it's generated at the server side.

Comment: I guess it will be difficult to help you without a sample

Comment: Hi,
Fixed the issue by passing the traceableExecutorPool to CompletableFuture.supplyAsync. Since restTemplate was getting executed in a new thread, which had no traceId associated with it. A new TraceId was being generated for each call to restTemplate.exchange.
`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class), traceableExecutorService)`

Somebody might find this useful :)

Comment: This example is available in the docs afair. The one with wrapping of a callable via Traceable ES. Anyways I'm happy that things are working for you! Can we mark this as answered?